# Android Ad-mob not displaying properly in all screens properly?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Hi all in one of my application am using AD-mob but it is not working properly in My devices ?
Here Am attached the screen shots ....!

[image: Level 8 Android 2.3 my ad-mob display like this] And

[image]

```
S2 device Ad-mob display like this it addjust all the screen
```

and In nexus 4 the Ad- mob displaying only off the screen why this happen any one idea of this issue help this one

am useing this code

XML

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/adBannerRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is Java code

```
    MMAdView adView = new MMAdView(activity);
        adView.setApid(" "); // id
        // Set your metadata in the MMRequest object
        MMRequest request = new MMRequest();
        // Add the MMRequest object to your MMAdView.
        adView.setMMRequest(request);
        // Sets the id to preserve your ad on configuration changes.
        adView.setId(MMSDK.getDefaultAdId());   
        //RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.cur_mainlayout);

        //view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.modified_news_layout, null);
        adRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.adBannerRelativeLayout);
        adRelativeLayout.addView(adView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    UtilityClass.dynamicScalingForWidth(46)));
        adRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);        
        adView.getAd();
```

Comment: first of all change your view width from fill_parent to match_parent..because it is deprecated...

Comment: @PiyushGupta changing ....

Comment: Okay...SO you need that your banner will be fit in all screen types devices???

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes ....

Comment: So there is a much way....you can use Displaymetrics or you can create a layout folder for different screen like large , xlarge,xhdpi ....

Comment: no present am use ing only one screen.........

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41471/discussion-between-nagarjunareddy-and-piyush-gupta)

Comment: change UtilityClass.dynamicScalingForWidth(46)) to LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT

Comment: when i change that thing admob display full screen but i want only bottam of the screen....

Comment: show your  full xml  file

Comment: Is your Admob SDK version updated ??
Sometimes it's also create issue.

Comment: I have not done it programmatically but I used the attribute  on an xml's tag `<com.google.ads.AdViewandroid:adSize="SMART_BANNER"/>` so the sdk manages the size [+info](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/smart-banners). Try at your code `adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER)`

Comment: @PiyushGupta http://pastebin.com/EgysDwpM

Comment: @Priyanka present am using 6.3.0.jar

Comment: No, i am talking about Google Admob Ads SDK. Which is present in Extras field of Android Sdk Manager.

Comment: @Priyanka i think if he is using ADT22 then it should be latest version of it...

Comment: use smart banner https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/smart-banners

Comment: @PiyushGupta Still same thing.....

Comment: have you change UtilityClass.dynamicScalingForWidth(46)) to LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT this also

Comment: @PiyushGupta same thing not working dude present add space also not showing..